# change addition weight of 2 layers in a model while training

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to add 2 layers in my model with different weights. I want to update these weights as the training goes on.

Example:

```
l1 = l1*(1-a)
l2 = l2*(a)
l3 = keras.layers.Add()([l1, l2])
```

Is there a way I can update the value of **'a'** linearly with each epoch?

Comment: It's unclear as to what the desired output you like. Can you provide a rough example of what you need?

Comment: I have 2 layers 'l1' and 'l2' in my keras model . I want an output which is weighted addition of these 2 layers. Is there a way so that i can change these weights with each epoch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import keras.backend as K

a = K.variable([0.5])

l1 = Lambda(lambda x: x * (1-a))(l1)
l2 = Lambda(lambda x: x * a)(l2)
l3 = keras.layers.Add()([l1,l2])
```

Change `a` with `K.set_value(a,[newValue])`

---

If you have dimensions mismatch (which I don't see in Keras 2.1.0 with tensorflow 1.4.0, and very very probably also works in newer versions), you can force a 4D `a` that matches your 4D data:

```
a = K.variable([[[[0.5]]]])
```

Comment: Can i set the value from outside the model function?

Comment: Yes. You can change values anywhere.

Comment: My layer is of size (64x64x3)
doing
    l1 = Lambda(lambda x: x * (1-a))(l1)
is giving me the error:
ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[3] = 64, input[2].shape[3] = 1)
 how do I multiply a scalar to a tensor?

Comment: It's working perfect for me... .what is your keras version? Is it tensoflow? Either way, you can force a 4D `a` by making `K.variable([[[[0.5]]]])`, and similarly in `set_value`.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. Even when forcing the tensor to be 4D

I'm using version 1.1.2 with theano backend

Comment: Ouch.... have you considered updating that? I think you will need to use a lot of `K.repeat_elements` to end up with the same shape of the input data.

Comment: i tried solving this problem by using 
    [a_var = K.ones(shape=(1,3,64,64))]
and updating the value during training by reassigning 
    [a_var = K.ones(shape=(1,3,64,64))*const]
where const is an int. But the update isnt being reflected in the model

Comment: No, you need `K.set_value()` to make the reassigment.